# Visual Studio Plugin to check the C++ Rule of 0 / Rule of 5

Tags: windows, gratis, visual-studio

I am looking for a Visual Studio (2019 and/or 2022) extension that identifies classes for me that do not adhere to the Rule of 0 or Rule of 5.

The extension may be a Resharper extension, since I own a Resharper license.

I have tried:

- enabling "code analysis on build" in Visual Studio. There is no warning for incorrect classes.
- enabling "C++ Core Check Class Rules". There are no warnings for incorrect classes